# Find the first N non-zero elements in each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in MATLAB with zeroes and I would like to get another matrix with the first `N` non-zero elements in each row. Let's say for example `N = 3`, and the matrix is

```
A = [ 0 0 2 0 6 7 9;
      3 2 4 7 0 0 6;
      0 1 0 3 4 8 6;
      1 2 0 0 0 1 3]
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
B = [2 6 7;
     3 2 4;
     1 3 4;
     1 2 1]
```

I have a huge matrix so I would like to do it without a loop, could you please help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have at least N non-zero elements in each row?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am guaranteed to have more than N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since MATLAB stores a matrix according to [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order), I first transpose `A`, bubble up the non-zeros, and pick the first `N` lines, and transpose back:

```
N = 3;
A = [ 0 0 2 0 6 7 9;
      3 2 4 7 0 0 6;
      0 1 0 3 4 8 6;
      1 2 0 0 0 1 3];
```

Transpose and preallocate output B

```
At = A';
B = zeros(size(At));

At =
     0     3     0     1
     0     2     1     2
     2     4     0     0
     0     7     3     0
     6     0     4     0
     7     0     8     1
     9     6     6     3
```

Index zeros

```
idx = At == 0;

idx =
     1     0     1     0
     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1
     1     0     0     1
     0     1     0     1
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Bubble up the non-zeros

```
B(~sort(idx)) = At(~idx);

B =
     2     3     1     1
     6     2     3     2
     7     4     4     1
     9     7     8     3
     0     6     6     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Select first `N` rows and transpose back

```
B(1:N,:)'
```

You can do the bubbling in row-major order, but you would need to retrieve the row and column subscripts with find, and do some sorting and picking there. It becomes more tedious and less readable.

Comment: Awesome! That's just what I needed!
Thank so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using `accumarray` with no loops:

```
N = 3;
[ii,jj] = find(A); [ii,inds]=sort(ii); jj = jj(inds);
lininds = ii+size(A,1)*(jj-1);
C = accumarray(ii,lininds,[],@(x) {A(x(1:N)')}); %' cell array output
B = vertcat(C{:})
B =
     2     6     7
     3     2     4
     1     3     4
     1     2     1
```

Comment: +1 I knew you would come up with an `accumarray` solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Usually I don't go with a for loop solution, but this is fairly intuitive:

```
N = 3;
[ii,jj] = find(A);
B = zeros(size(A,1),N);
for iRow = 1:size(A,1),
    nzcols = jj(ii==iRow);
    B(iRow,:) = A(iRow,nzcols(1:N));
end
```

Since you are guaranteed to have more than `N` nonzeros per row of `A`, that should get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

```
N = 3;
for ii=1:size(A,1);
    B(ii,:) = A( ii,find(A(ii,:),N) );
end
```

Comment: I always forget about the `'first'` usage. +1 for the reminder.

Comment: @chappjc in this case actually not even necessary, at least `'first'` is the default

Comment: Actually I meant the second argument, which is default first as you point out.  I never use that.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner solution:

```
B = cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) c(1:N), arrayfun(@(k) nonzeros(A(k,:)), 1:size(A,1), 'uni', false), 'uni', false)).'
```

Not terribly elegant or efficient, but so much fun!

Comment: Extra points for a single line, can't fault you there.  Not exactly faster than a loop as you point out.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually , you can do it like the code blow:

---

```
N=3
 for n=1:size(A,1)
   [a b]=find(A(n,:)>0,N);
   B(n,:)=A(n,transpose(b));
end
```

---

Then I think this B matrix will be what you want.