# Finding all indices by ismember

Tags: matlab

This is what is described in one of the examples for [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

> Define two vectors with values in common.
>
> `A = [5 3 4 2]; B = [2 4 4 4 6 8];`
>
> Determine which elements of `A` are also in `B` as well as their corresponding locations in `B`.
>
> `[Lia,Locb] = ismember(A,B)`

The result is:

```
Lia =
     0     0     1     1

Locb =    
     0     0     2     1
```

The element in `B` with the lowest index that matches `A(3)` is `B(2)`. `A(4)` equals `B(1)`. Is there a way by which we could find *all* the indices of the elemets of `B` matching the same element in `A`?

Comment: Have you reviewed any of the suggested answers? If you found any of them helpful, please consider voting them up and possibly marking one of them as accepted.

Comment: @user3077261 You do have several good answers here, as Eitan said. Upvote any answer(s) you find helpful and/or provides a working solution, then see what you like best for your problem and accept (click the checkbox).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can swap the input arguments to `ismember`:

```
[tf, ia] = ismember(B, A)
```

For your example, you should get:

```
tf =
     1     1     1     1     0     0

ia = 
     4     3     3     3     0     0
```

This allows you to find, say, the indices of all the elements of `B` that equal `A(3)` simply by doing:

```
find(ia == 3)
```

Here's a nifty solution for the general case:

```
[tf, ia] = ismember(B, A);
idx = 1:numel(B);
ib = accumarray(nonzeros(ia), idx(tf), [], @(x){x});
```

Note that the output is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). For your example, you should get:

```
ib = 
    []
    []
    [2     3     4]
    [      1]
```

which means that there are no elements in `B` matching `A(1)` and `A(2)`, `A(3)` matches elements `B(2)`, `B(3)` and `B(4)`, and `A(4)` equals `B(1)`.

Comment: Excellent use of `accumarray` to encapsulate the indexes for unique elements in cells. +1 I've used cell output precisely [once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20255070/2778484) before and it was completely academic, but I have a feeling I'll be doing this more in the future.

Comment: And what if both A and B contain non-unique elements, say A = [5 3 4 4 2] and B = [2 4 4 4 6 8] (i.e. both A and B contain multiple entries of 4)?

Comment: @Confounded Good question. In short, the current solutoin won't work if `A` contains non-unique elements. It can, however, be extended to support that...

Answer (score 4):

This line will return all indices:

```
F=arrayfun(@(x)(find(A(x)==B)),1:numel(A),'UniformOutput',false)
```

Or a longer version, which might be easier to read:

```
F=cell(numel(A),1);
for x=1:numel(A)
  F{x}=find(A(x)==B);
end
```

`find(A(x)==B)` checks for all occurrences of `A(x)` in `B`. This is done for each element of the array, either using a for loop or `arrayfun`.

Comment: Can you please explain what will this line actually do. I am new at this.BTW thanks.

Comment: What if the entries are in text, and imported as column vectors?

Comment: @user3077261: And what output is intended? Search for words? For Substrings? Single characters?

Comment: @user3077261 If the entries are in text, that's out of the original question. You asked about two numeric vectors without regard as to how they are imported

Comment: I am just asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to use `bsxfun` to test for equality between each element of `A` and  `B`:

```
ind = bsxfun(@eq, A(:), B(:).');
list = cellfun(@find, mat2cell(ind, ones(1,numel(A)), numel(B)), 'uni', 0);
```

The matrix `ind` gives the result in logical form (i.e. 0 or 1 values), and `list` is a cell array containing the indices:

```
>>  ind

ind =

     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0

>> celldisp(list)

list{1} =

     []


list{2} =

     []    

list{3} =

     2     3     4

list{4} =

     1
```

Comment: Clever use of `mat2cell` to break up the output. +1 I've found that `mat2cell` and `cellfun` make a great team. It's a tossup between this and Eitan's answer, but you know how I feel about `accumarray`.  :)

Comment: @chappjc When I saw this question, the `accumarray`-based answer had already been given. But at least I could use `bsxfun`, which is another of my favourites :-)

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solutions (i.e. those without using iterations of `find`) involve swapping the inputs to `ismember` and grouping like indexes with `accumarray`, as in Eitan's answer, or vectorizing the find with `bsxfun` as in Luis Mendo's answer, IMHO.

However, for those interested in a solution with undocumented functionality, and an admittedly hackish approach, here is another way to do it (i.e. for each element of `A`, find the indexes of all corresponding elements in `B`).  The thinking goes as follows: In a sorted `B`, what if you had the first *and* last indexes of each matching element? It turns out there are two helper functions used by `ismember` (if you have R2012b+, I think) that will give you both of these indexes: `_ismemberfirst` (a `builtin`) and `ismembc2`.

For the example data `A = [5 3 4 2]; B = [2 4 4 4 6 8];` in the question, here is the implementation:

```
[Bs,sortInds] = sort(B); % nop for this B, but required in general
firstInds = builtin('_ismemberfirst',A,Bs) % newish version required
firstInds =
     0     0     2     1
lastInds = ismembc2(A,Bs)
lastInds =
     0     0     4     1
```

The heavy lifting is now done - We have the first *and* last indexes in `B` for *each* element in `A` without having to do any looping. There is no occurrence of `A(1)` or `A(2)` (5 or 3) in `B`, so those indexes are `0`. The value 4 (`A(3)`) occurs at locations 2:4 (i.e. `all(B(2:4)==A(3))`). Similarly, `A(4)` is found at `B(1:1)`.

We are able to ignore `sortInds` in the above example since `B` is already sorted, but an unsorted `B` is handled by simply looking up the locations in the unsorted array. We can quickly do this lookup and package each range of indexes with `arrayfun`, keeping in mind that the computationally intensive task of actually finding the indexes is already done:

```
allInds = arrayfun(@(x,y)sortInds(x:y-(x==0)),firstInds,lastInds,'uni',0)
allInds = 
    [1x0 double]    [1x0 double]    [1x3 double]    [1]
```

Each cell has the indexes in `B` (if any) of each element of `A`. The first two cells are empty arrays, as expected. Looking closer at the third element:

```
>> allInds{3}
ans =
     2     3     4
>> A(3)
ans =
     4
>> B(allInds{3})
ans =
     4     4     4
```

Testing operation with unsorted `B`:

```
B(4:5) = B([5 4])
B =
     2     4     4     6     4     8

[Bs,sortInds] = sort(B);
firstInds = builtin('_ismemberfirst',A,Bs);
lastInds = ismembc2(A,Bs);
allInds = arrayfun(@(x,y)sortInds(x:y-(x==0)),firstInds,lastInds,'uni',0);

allInds{3} % of A(3) in B
ans =
     2     3     5

B(allInds{3})
ans =
     4     4     4
```

Is it worth doing it this way, with a penalty for `sort` and two effective `ismember` calls? Maybe not, but I think it's an interesting solution. If you have a sorted `B`, it's even faster since the two built-in functions assume the second argument (`Bs`) is sorted and waste no time with checks. Try and see what works for you.

Comment: It seemed like all possible approaches had already been explored, but then @chappjc came along... +1

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of Eitan T. and Daniel R answer your question in total. My solution is a convenient and simpler alternative if **you are just interested in the elements which are common in both vectors, but NOT how they are related in means of `ismember`, e.g. you just want to filter your data for common elements:**

I would use the inversion of the opposite: `setxor`

```
A = [5 3 4 2]; 
B = [2 4 4 4 6 8];

[~,iai,ibi] = setxor(A,B);   % elements which are not in common
ia = 1:numel(A);
ib = 1:numel(B);
ia(iai) = [];                %indices of elements of B in A
ib(ibi) = [];                %indices of elements of A in B
```

**Or just the same thing twice:**

```
[~,iai,ibi] = setxor(A,B);
ia = setxor(1:numel(A),iai);
ib = setxor(1:numel(B),ibi);
```

---

returns in both cases the indices of the elements also existing in the respective other vector, so to say an implementation of **`~isnotmember`**

```
ia =

     3     4

ib =

     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: How does this result tell, for instance, that `A(3)` matches elements #2, #3 and #4 in `B`?

Comment: @EitanT:  It doesn't. The question is whether that is important. But I rethink about it.

Comment: The question is about finding the indices of all elements in `B` that match the elements in `A`...

Comment: @EitanT: I see the point, and that this is a mayor drawback. But I could imagine cases where the relation between the elements is just not important, than it's a quite convenient solution.

Comment: @EitanT: I admit that your solution (as well as Daniel R's) answers the question in total and mine not. I stated that clearly now in my answer. I think it's still a good answer depending on the use of `ismember` intended by the OP