# find row indices of different values in matrix

Tags: matlab, find, row, cell, indices

Having matrix A (n*2) as the source and B as a vector containing a subset of elements A, I'd like to find the row index of items.

```
A=[1 2;1 3; 4 5];
B=[1 5];
F=arrayfun(@(x)(find(B(x)==A)),1:numel(B),'UniformOutput',false)
```

gives the following outputs in a cell [according to this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452883/finding-all-indices-by-ismember)

```
[2x1 double]    [6]
```

indicating the indices of all occurrence in column-wise. But I'd like to have the indices of rows. i.e. I'd like to know that element 1 happens in row 1 and row 2 and element 5 happens just in row 3. If the indices were row-wise I could use ceil(F{x}/2) to have the desired output. Now with the variable number of rows, what's your suggested solution? As it may happens that there's no complete inclusion tag 'rows' in ismember function does not work. Besides, I'd like to know all indices of specified elements.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Approach 1

To convert `F` from its current [linear-index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) form into row indices, use [`mod`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html):

```
rows = cellfun(@(x) mod(x-1,size(A,1))+1, F, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

You can combine this with your code into a single line. Note also that you can directly use `B` as an input to `arrayfun`, and you avoid one stage of indexing:

```
rows = arrayfun(@(x) mod(find(x==A)-1,size(A,1))+1, B(:), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

**How this works**:

`F` as given by your code is a linear index in column-major form. This means the index runs down the first column of `B`, the begins at the top of the second column and runs down again, etc. So the row number can be obtained with just a modulo (`mod`) operation.

### Approach 2

Using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
t = any(bsxfun(@eq, B(:), reshape(A, 1, size(A,1), size(A,2))), 3); %// occurrence pattern
[ii, jj] = find(t); %// ii indicates an element of B, and jj is row of A where it occurs
rows = accumarray(ii, jj, [], @(x) {x}); %// group results according to ii
```

**How this works**:

Assuming `A` and `B` as in your example, `t` is the 2x3 matrix

```
t =
     1     1     0
     0     0     1
```

The *m*-th row of `t` contains `1` at column *n* if the *m*-th element of `B` occurs at the *n*-th row of `B`. These values are converted into row and column form with `find`:

```
ii =
     1
     1
     2
jj =
     1
     2
     3
```

This means the first element of `B` ocurrs at rows 1 and 2 of `A`; and the second occurs at row 3 of `B`.

Lastly, the values of `jj` are grouped (with `accumarray`) according to their corresponding value of `ii` to generate the desired result.

Comment: Perfect solution. I think your first approach is faster than all other approaches, yes? Will you give some explanation on your delicate precise solution?

Comment: You mean explanation for the second (`bsxfun` and `accumarray`), right?

Comment: I try to figure out using keyword links and other helps.Thanks and God bless you:)

Comment: We ended with one similar approach, at least the alternative approaches are different :)

Comment: @hamideh I've added explanations for both. In the second, it may be useful also to look at the intermediate result `bsxfun(@eq, B(:), reshape(A, 1, size(A,1), size(A,2)))`

Comment: @Divakar Yes, your first method and my second one are almost the same, except some dimensions are swapped :-)

Comment: @Divakar : In fact, I'm using in clustering context and i have two cellarray. cellarrayA containing dtailed link info and weight information (one cell for every cluster) and cellarrayB containing unique node ids in first row and corresponding weights in row2. So, I have to find row numbers of cellarrayA which I can use to traverse into cellarrayA and add the weights for every node (I asked the question in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272692/find-index-of-all-numeric-values-in-a-cell-array)). Using your suggested answer, I'm gonna to find the solution..

Comment: @hamideh Alright, I meant to ask for the sizes of A and B, to see how these approaches would perform for runtimes. Do you know their sizes?

Comment: @Divakar: I've 50 epoch of nearly 500 link info. So about 25000 link info. So A is about 500 for every cluster and B around 100. Bigger efficiency problems may reside in the choice of my datastructure and storing fashion. I was first using array  of structure and it was too slow; I turned to cell-array. Will you please take a look at my question in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272692/find-index-of-all-numeric-values-in-a-cell-array). Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

One approach with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) & [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) -

```
%// Create a match of B's in A's with each column of matches representing the
%// rows in A where there is at least one match for each element in B 
matches = squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(B(:),[3 2 1])),2))

%// Get the indices values and the corresponding IDs of B
[indices,B_id] = find(matches)
%// Or directly for performance:
%// [indices,B_id] = find(any(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(B(:),[3 2 1])),2))

%// Accumulate the indices values using B_id as subscripts
out = accumarray(B_id(:),indices(:),[],@(x) {x})
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2
     1     3
     4     5
>> B
B =
     1     5
>> celldisp(out) %// To display the output, out
out{1} =
     1
     2
out{2} =
     3
```

Comment: Exact and awesome... Just will you please explain a bit your solution for me?

Comment: @hamideh See if the edited comments help it explain?

Comment: I try to figure out using keyword links and other helps.Thanks and God bless you:)

Comment: @Divakar +1 for the `bsxfun` approach BTW, are you sure the alternate method is giving desired output?

Comment: @SanthanSalai You are right! Removed that approach.

Answer (score 1):

With [`arrayfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html),[`ismember`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) and [`find`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)

```
[r,c] = arrayfun(@(x) find(ismember(A,x)) , B, 'uni',0);
```

Where `r` gives your desired results, you could also use the `c` variable to get the column of each number in `B`

**Results for the sample input:**

```
>> celldisp(r)

r{1} =
 1
 2

r{2} = 
 3


>> celldisp(c)

c{1} = 
 1
 1

c{2} =
 2
```