# in matlab,how can i put all zeros in the end of the rows in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

i want to put all the zero elemets of a matrix to the end of the rows. For example if i have A=[1 0 2 0 3 0;1 3 0 2 0 5;0 2 4 0 1 0] i want it to become A=[1 2 3 0 0 0;1 3 2 5 0 0;2 4 1 0 0 0]

```
Like,  A=[1 0 2 0 3 0   to     A=[1 2 3 0 0 0
          1 3 0 2 0 5             1 3 2 5 0 0    
          0 2 4 0 1 0]            2 4 1 0 0 0]
```

is there any way of doing this in matlab?

Comment: the answer is here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254172/find-the-first-n-non-zero-elements-in-each-row-of-a-matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254172/find-the-first-n-non-zero-elements-in-each-row-of-a-matrix)

Comment: Thanks. I have flagged it as a duplicate.